# window.getch() does not return the same codes as main_screen.getch()

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

I have encoding issues with ncurses (linux).
I'm trying to replicate in Python [example 7](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/windows.html) of the ncurses Programming HOWTO in C.
I did manage to get the example running.

```py
import curses

@curses.wrapper
def main(main_screen):
    w, h = 5, 3
    x, y = curses.COLS // 2, curses.LINES // 2

    def mkwin(w, h, x, y):
        win = curses.newwin(h, w, y, x)
        win.box(0, 0)
        win.refresh()
        return win

    def clearwin(win):
        win.border(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ')
        win.refresh()

    main_screen.addstr("Press Q to quit.")
    main_screen.refresh()
    testwin = mkwin(w, h, x, y)

    while True:
        key = main_screen.getch()
        if key in {curses.KEY_BACKSPACE, ord('q')}:
            break
        if key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
            clearwin(testwin)
            del testwin
            x -= 1
            testwin = mkwin(w, h, x, y)
        if key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
            clearwin(testwin)
            del testwin
            x += 1
            testwin = mkwin(w, h, x, y)
        if key == curses.KEY_UP:
            clearwin(testwin)
            del testwin
            y -= 1
            testwin = mkwin(w, h, x, y)
        if key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
            clearwin(testwin)
            del testwin
            y += 1
            testwin = mkwin(w, h, x, y)
```

However I wanted to remove the first screen that has that `"Press Q to quit."` message.
So I changed

```
    main_screen.addstr("Press Q to quit.")
    main_screen.refresh()
    testwin = mkwin(w, h, x, y)
```

to

```
    testwin = mkwin(w, h, x, y)
```

But instead I had an empty first screen that would stay until I press a key.  Apparently, the `getch()` function of `main_screen` cause the entire screen to clear, so I have to use the `getch()` of the `testwin`.

However the `testwin.getch()` method does not return a nice integer code for a single key press : it returns instead tweak key codes. E.g. for Key Up it returns `27` then `91` instead of the single `259` `main_screen.getch()` returns. How do I configure `testwin` so that `getch` returns the value for `testwin` as for `main_screen` ?

*Note*: I've tried to use `main_screen.subwin` instead of `curses.newwin`, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python curses ["wrapper"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.wrapper) calls the [`keypad`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.keypad) method, which is not the default for `newwin`.  The [source code](https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/69fe0ffd2d85b4002cacae1f28ef2eb0f25e16ae/Lib/curses/wrapper.py#L29) does this:

```
    # In keypad mode, escape sequences for special keys
    # (like the cursor keys) will be interpreted and
    # a special value like curses.KEY_LEFT will be returned
    stdscr.keypad(1)
```

If you add `win.keypad(1)`, it'll solve that problem.